# How to make this feature clear about what it really does?

Tags: wording, features

I built a service in which you can browse html/css buttons and add new ones to the collection. When on a button's detail page you can access to the code, live edit it and see the result when clicking on a preview button. The fork button takes you to the add page while keeping the edited code so you can upload a new one on top of this.

**Actually, I'm not sure if the "fork this button" feature is clear ? Would "Duplicate this button" be better ?**

Current UI :

[image: zoo buttons interface]

**EDIT :** It seems like it's not that easy to explain what the feature does so let's say we're in Photoshop. You opened a file, made some changes. In this case, the fork button would create a new (unsaved) document from the current by keeping the changes but not altering the original file.

Comment: So fork recreates the button?

Comment: @MervinJohnsingh not really, fork will fill the code areas with the button's code on the add page. You'll still have to click on "add this button" then to create it.

Comment: A function like adobes' save a copy...?

Comment: @Bluewater actually it's more like "create a new button from this one". In Photoshop it would create a new (unsaved) file with the same layers and keep the changes you made without changing anything to the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Since technically the idea is to copy the buttons code, I would use a simple text such as "**Use this button's code**" which will allow the user to know what will happen when he clicks on the option.

Another option is "**Generate button code**"

If your button is completely via CSS, you can do what [button Maker](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/) does which is given below

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of "Use this button's code" but do you think it's clear the button won't copy the code or export it but take it to a new form ?